# Does "Magewell Pro Capture HDMI 4K" support 144Hz input?

Tags: video, screen-capture

I'm looking for a capture card that supports a native 1440p, 144Hz input. I think I've found one in the [Magewell Pro Capture HDMI 4K](http://www.magewell.com/pro-capture-hdmi-4k). But, I have a question regarding it.

I want to configure a 2 PC streaming setup, where one PC is a gaming PC, and the other is the streaming PC. My gaming PC has a 1440p, 144Hz BenQ monitor. I want a capture card that I can simply connect to and configure windows to mirror my displays without sacrificing resolution or refresh rate (which is what is needed for the more common cards, like elgato and avermedia).

My question, about the Magewell card, is does it support 144Hz refresh rate? If I configure Windows to just mirror displays, will the Magewell show up as supporting 144Hz?

It looks like it very easily supports the 1440p resolution, so I'm not concerned there. But, my confusion about the refresh rate comes from their [tech spec sheet](http://www.magewell.com/pro-capture-hdmi-4k/tech-specs), which uses the terminology "fps". It says it supports 144 fps. Here's the exact wording ...

> Support for capture frame rates up to 144fps. (Actual capture frame
>   rate can be limited by PCIe bandwidth & image resolution)

Comment: I would contact Magewell support...http://www.magewell.com/support

Answer (score 0):

"Hz" is basically "Frames per Second" or FPS. That being said the spec sheets lists "~360Mpixels/s processing bandwidth" per lane with a max of two lanes, on a pcix2 slot.

This means MATH!

```
2 x 360Mp = 720Mp/s

4096 x 2160 = 8.8Mp
```

needed per second

Max "Hz/FPS" at 2160P is thus 60hz (Down from actual of 80hz)

At 1440p or below Hz can get up to 144hz

Answer (score -2):

on a hdmi cable it is impossible to reach 144hz, they reach about 80 max.
it would require display port or multiple hdmi cable inputs.

Comment: Oh? HDMI 2.1 can do 3840 × 2160 at 144 Hz ... it can even do 240 Hz with DSC https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Refresh_frequency_limits_for_standard_video

Comment: A collegue of mine uses a 144Hz 1440p monitor on HDMI. Nothing special, regular HDMI cable.